# Spring 2.6.7: Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute

Tags: mysql, spring, database, configuration, application.properties

I have created a new Spring Starter Project and I specified in application.properties the db settings:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useUnicode=yes&character_set_server=utf8mb4
spring.datasource.username=.....
spring.datasource.password=.....
```

in pom.xml I have the mysql dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have also done `maven -> Update`....

When starting the project the console says:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

I don´t understand..i just provided what he needs...the datasource.url...

When I change the spring version to `2.3.0.RELEASE`...it works. But why not with the `newer one 2.6.7` (which should be stable)?

Comment: The data source properties which you mentioned above work with spring boot 2.6.7(No issues). Maybe you should sync, clean, and install the project one more time.

Comment: strange, i don´t understand why it occurs with me and others... any idea? which code do you need to see to analyze that?

Comment: I created "mydb" and used the same data source properties and application running. For analysing purposes the data source properties you have given is 5n. But it would be good if you can add your pom file. Are you configuring a DataSource(extra) Programmatically?.If possible delete the project from the workspace and import it again. Or most probably a cache issue.